# Getting a value from Embedded View in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I have probably a very simple problem but got stuck on it
I have a form inside it i have a field and for it i want to take value from a embedded view has anybody a idea how to accomplish it.

Comment: What do you mean by "take a value from a embedded view". There can be lots of values in each document that appears in an embedded view, so what value do you want, and how do you (and your code) know you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a value from an embedded view from the "surrounding" document is not possible. But the opposite direction definitely is.

In the code of all events / actions in the embedded view you can use the following code to get the surrounding document:

```vb
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc as NotesUIDocument
```

Then you could set fields on base of the currently selected document in the view e.g. in the event Onselect (new since Version 8) you could place some code like this (partly taken from Desiger help of event Onselect ):

```vb
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc as NotesUIDocument
Dim lastCaretID As Variant
lastCaretID = "000"
Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument

Sub Onselect(Source As Notesuiview)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase 
    caretNoteID$ = Source.CaretNoteID
    If lastCaretID <> caretNoteID$ Then   ' we only process if the highlighted row has changed
        lastCaretID = caretNoteID$
        noteID$ = "NT00000" + caretNoteID$
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID( caretNoteID$ )
        Call uidoc.Document.ReplaceItemValue( "SelectedSubject", doc.GetitemValue( "Subject") )
    End If
End Sub
```

Take care: Calling `uidoc.Refresh` / `uidoc.Reload` from within code in the embedded view context will most certainly crash your Notes- Client, so don#t do this...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way to do that in classic Notes. You may have to rethink your design/approach. I would use a picklist dialog box for this.

I am sure you can do that in XPages, or if this is a web application it would not be that difficult to do with Javascript/jQuery.